# trying to get counter to decrease through number generator game

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am having problems with creating a decreasing counter every time you guess the wrong number in this number guessing game. I have previously done this project with success but wanted to try challenge myself with implementing it with tkinter, I am new to python so not too sure where i am going wrong.

here is the code:

```
import random
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter


root = ctk.CTk()
ctk.set_appearance_mode('dark')
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
root.geometry('800x800')
root.title('Name Guessing Game')

random_number = random.randint(1, 100)
global counter
counter = 8
n_var = tkinter.StringVar(root, value='hint')


def low():
    print('Higher')


def high():
    print('Lower')

def won():
    print('You Guessed Correctly!!!!')


def submit(counter, chances_counter):
    
    global number
    number = 0

    while number != random_number and counter != 0:
        number = int(number_guess.get())
        if number < random_number:
            n_var.set(value='Too low go higher')
            counter -= 1
            chances_counter.configure(text=counter)
            return low()

        elif number > random_number:
            n_var.set(value='Too high go lower')
            counter -= 1
            chances_counter.configure(text=counter)
            return high()

        else:
            n_var.set(value='')
            return won()
            break

#GUI


frame_title = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=20)
frame_title.pack(pady=(20, 20), padx=20, fill='x')

frame_guess = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=20)
frame_guess.pack(side='top', ipady=80, fill='x', padx=20)

frame_hint = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=20)
frame_hint.pack(side='top', ipady=80, fill='x', padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

frame_answer = ctk.CTkFrame(master=root, corner_radius=20)
frame_answer.pack(side='top', ipady=80, fill='x', padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

title_block = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame_title, text='Number Guessing Game!', font=ctk.CTkFont(size=30))
title_block.pack(pady=80)

# guess input
number_guess = ctk.CTkEntry(master=frame_guess, placeholder_text='number to guess')
number_guess.pack(side='left', padx=20)

# guess submit
button = ctk.CTkButton(master=frame_guess, text='submit', command=lambda:[submit(counter, chances_counter), answer_a()])
button.pack(side='left')

#chances left


chances_counter = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame_guess, text=counter, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=18))
chances_counter.pack(side='right', padx=20)

chances_counter1 = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame_guess, text='How many chances left:', font=ctk.CTkFont(size=16))
chances_counter1.pack(side='right')

#hint


hint_lower = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame_hint, textvariable=n_var, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=16))
hint_lower.pack(side='left',fill='both', expand=True, padx=20)


#answer
a_var = tkinter.StringVar(root, value='')
def answer_a():
    if number == random_number:
        a_var.set(value='Congratultions you guessed right!!!')
    


hint_answer = ctk.CTkLabel(master=frame_answer, textvariable=a_var, font=ctk.CTkFont(size=16))
hint_answer.pack(side='left',fill='both', expand=True, padx=20)


root.mainloop()
```

any help would be appreciated.

The closest I have gotten to decreased the counter is by using this:

```
counter -= 1
chances_counter.configure(text=counter)
```

It seems to work for the first try as soon as you load the game and put your first answer in it will decrease by 1, but it will not happen each time.

Comment: It looks like you're passing `counter` into the `submit` function, which means `counter -= 1` happens to a local copy of the counter.

You should be able to change the signature to `def submit(chances_counter)` and add put `global counter` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Try NOT passing counter as paramter in submit, since counter is already defined  as global in code.

Comment: @SimonCrowe that did the trick thank you very much its working how it should now